# How to pass a NSString object to stringByAppendingFormat:

Tags: iphone

How to pass a `NSString` object to stringByAppendingFormat in objective c.

I am able to append string as:

```
NSString *aString =[name stringByAppendingFormat:@"Hello"];
```

but its not being possible to use an object of NSString for appending for example in my case

```
NSString *aString =self.stringName;
NSString *resultString =[name stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aString]];
```

what has to be changed in the above code ?

Comment: Don't forget to accept questions witch helps you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you must try in this way ?

```
NSString *aString  = self.stringName;
NSString * tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aString];
NSString *resultString =[name stringByAppendingFormat:tempStr];
```

Comment: thank you so much this is working for me   NSString *format =@".png";
 NSString * tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",format];
 fileName =[name stringByAppendingString:tempStr];
 NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName]);

Answer (score 4):

When using stringByAppendingFormat you are going to need a format.
If you just want to append you should use:

```
NSString *aString =self.stringName;
NSString *resultString =[name stringByAppendingString:aString];
```

or

```
NSString *aString =self.stringName;
NSString *resultString =[name stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",aString];
```